# \sqrtsign and \sqrt

Tags: symbols

The following lines caught my attention while browsing `source2e` while looking for the definition of another command.

```
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{symbols}{"70}{largesymbols}{"70}
```

and

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[\@sqrt\sqrtsign}
\def\@sqrt[#1]{\root #1\of}
```

What was `\sqrtsign` for? I tried `\sqrtsign{x}` and it outputs something similar to `\sqrt{x}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of LaTeX's `\sqrt` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[\@sqrt\sqrtsign}
\def\@sqrt[#1]{\root #1\of}
```

which means that if the optional argument is used (i.e., if the next character after `\sqrt` is `[`), `\@sqrt` is used (and this in its turn, uses `\root#1\of`
 whose definition can be found on page 210 of `source2e.pdf`) to typeset the radical index and the subradical expression; if no optional argument is given,`\sqrtsign` is used to typeset the subradical expression (`\sqrtsign` doesn't allow an optional argument).

Comment: Thank whoever invented the find text and go to page capabilities of document readers:)