# "Esami" package: \randestrai and \sqrt not working together?

Tags: packages, compilation-error, random, esami, sqrt

The `\randestrai` command from the "esami" package allows to define a set of elements to randomly choose within, such as a set of formulas. It works with formulas including latex commands inside, for example I can safely use

```
\randestrai{\frac{1}{2}x+1,2x-\frac{1}{2}}{formula}
```

or

```
\randestrai{A \to B, \overline{A} \land B}{formula}
```

but once I use the `\sqrt` command in one of the elements an error messages arises telling me that there is an extra "}" that actually doesn't exists.

Example: if I write

```
\randestrai{\sqrt 2, 1}{formula}
```

I get the error message:

> ! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.  \par l.10
>   \randestrai{\sqrt 2, 1}{formula} I've run across a `}' that doesn't
>   seem to match anything.

Why is that? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\sqrt` is a risky command to put there (it depends on how `\randestrai` is implemented).

Make it robust in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esami}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\sqrt}

\date{2018/11/02}

\begin{document}

\randestrai{\frac{1}{2}x+1,2x-\frac{1}{2}}{formula}
$\formulai$

\randestrai{A \to B, \overline{A} \land B}{formula}
$\formulai$

\randestrai{\sqrt{4+3}, \sqrt{2+5}}{formula}
$\formulai$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `\sqrt` is `\@ifnextchar [\@sqrt \sqrtsign` (see [\sqrtsign and \sqrt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75105/sqrtsign-and-sqrt)), which checks for an optional argument (the root number). It seems that the list processing in `\randestrai` breaks in some way because of this definition. As a workaround you can bypass the check and directly use `\sqrtsign` for a square root without the number.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esami}
\date{2018/04/21}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\begin{document}
\randestrai{\frac{1}{2}x+1,2x-\frac{1}{2}}{formula}
$\formulai$

\randestrai{A \to B, \overline{A} \land B}{formula}
$\formulai$

\randestrai{\sqrtsign{4+3}, \sqrtsign{2+5}}{formula}
$\formulai$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Edit: in general, but especially for adding indexes, the [solution of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458004/) is preferred. However, you can define a square root command that can be used in `\randestrai` without being robust:

```
\def\sqsciatto#1#2{{}^{\scriptscriptstyle #2}\mkern-11mu\sqrtsign{#1}}

\randestrai{\sqsciatto{4+3}{7}, \sqsciatto{2+5}{3}}{formula}
$\formulai$
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Good idea but it seems it wouldn't work if I want roots with indexes different from 2

Comment: Indeed, for that you should use [egregs answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458004/). But it can be done with a but of trouble, see edit.